# While scanning character array it wont submit when hitting [ENTER KEY]

Tags: arrays, c, scanf, codeblocks

Hi I am beginner in programming and in C. I am trying to scan a character array but when I hit enter instead of submitting my input it go to the next line and then typing any character and hitting enter it submit, What is wrong with my code? by the way I am using a CodeBlocks IDE. Thanks, sorry for noob question I can't find any answer.

EDITED: I Answered my own question lol I realize I add `\n` in `scanf` function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
  char name[21];
  printf("what is your name\n");
  scanf("%s\n", name);

  printf("%s\n", name);

  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quick fix: Don't have trailing white-space (like newline) in a `scanf` format string. So instead of `scanf("%s\n", name)` have `scanf("%s", name)`. The reason is that it will cause `scanf` to skip all trailing white-space characters, but to know when to stop that there needs to be some non-space input.

Comment: ohh yeah lol sorry im using new text editor and it auto add that newline I forgot to remove.

Comment: Do not use `scanf("%s\n", name);` or `scanf("%s", name);`, they are worse than `gets()`.  Use a width limit `char name[21]; ...scanf("%20s", name);`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica sometime if a do recursion if I add 2 or more characters that needs a single character only in `scanf`, it recurse automatically because it has a remaining character, is width limit can fix that? what is the benefits that width limit do?

Comment: Pyromagne, A _width_ prevents too much input from being saved in `name[]`.  Consider if code tried to save 30 characters in `name[]` --> disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is in the comment by @some programmer dude.
I forget that I add `\n` into `scanf("%s", name)` like this `scanf("%s\n", name)`